# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: row in

Tags: php

I am trying to deal with this error, it show notice undefined variable row in line.. This my code:

```
<?php
  include('include/db.php');
  include('include/function.php');  
  if(isset($_GET['services'])){            
        $result=$Con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_about_n_servciesub WHERE sub_id={$_GET['services']}");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_object($result);
  echo $row->description;
  }
?>
```

Comment: you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: What line is the undefined variable notice?

Comment: You haven't declared variable $row when assigning `mysqli_fetch_object($result)` to it

Comment: Full error message....